# Checkout shipping address - customer first name and last name prefilled

Tags: magento2.3.1, checkout-page

I have a request from a customer, he wants, when adding a new address during checkout, to stop magento to fill in First Name and Last Name with the Customer Information.

I went through all files from Magento_Checkout I cant find the place where first name and last name are set onto the shipping address.

in onepage.phtml a script grabs customer data

```
    window.checkoutConfig = <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getSerializedCheckoutConfig() ?>;
    // Create aliases for customer.js model from customer module
    window.isCustomerLoggedIn = window.checkoutConfig.isCustomerLoggedIn;
    window.customerData = window.checkoutConfig.customerData;
```

I even tried to manipulate the data here and replace first name and last name with "" but nothing happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following way:

> app/code/SR/CheckoutStep/etc/frontend/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor">
        <plugin name="sr_checkout_layout_processor_t" type="SR\CheckoutStep\Plugin\Block\LayoutProcessor" sortOrder="10"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

> app/code/SR/CheckoutStep/Plugin/Block/LayoutProcessor.php

```
<?php
namespace SR\CheckoutStep\Plugin\Block;


class LayoutProcessor
{
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject
     * @param array $jsLayout
     * @return array
     */
    public function afterProcess(
        \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject,
        array $jsLayout
    ) {

        $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']
        ['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']['firstname']['value'] = '';

        $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']
        ['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']['lastname']['value'] = '';

        return $jsLayout;
    }
}
```